# How to get attributes from xml?

Tags: xml, jsp, attributes, tags, jstl

How to get attributes from inside the tag of an xml with jstl in a jsp file?

for example:
< tag1 att1="value1" > hello world < / tag1 >

I want this string: att1="value1"

actually I can show value 'hello world' using:
< c: out value="${tag1.textValue}" / >

Answer (score 0):

At least,
someone can tell me how is the name of:

This part: att1="value1"

From: < tag1 att1="value1" > hello world < / tag1 >